# Can't resolve Dart App Engine dependency

Tags: google-app-engine, dart, angular-dart, dart-pub

I am trying to build a Dart application for Google App Engine but Dart can't resolve any appengine dependency except for the 0.0.1 version. Here is my pubspec.yaml:

```
name: MyApp
version: 0.0.1
dependencies:
  angular2: 2.0.0-alpha.44
  browser: ^0.10.0
  appengine: '>=0.3.0 < 0.4.0'
transformers:
- angular2:
    entry_points: web/main.dart
```

This is the error I get:

```
Package appengine has no versions that match >=0.3.0 <0.4.0 derived from:
- MyApp depends on version >=0.3.0 <0.4.0
```

I have tried every appengine version from https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/appengine/versions but the only one that works is ^0.0.1

```
Downloading appengine 0.0.1...
Got dependencies!
```

I would really like to use something newer than 0.0.1. Is something broken or am I missing something?

*Update:
I ran in verbose mode as per Günter Zöchbauer's suggestion and this is the output:

```
ERR : Package appengine has no versions that match >=0.0.2 <0.4.0 derived from:
    | - MyApp depends on version >=0.0.2 <0.4.0
FINE: Exception type: NoVersionException
FINE: package:pub/src/entrypoint.dart 154      Entrypoint.acquireDependencies.<async>
    | ===== asynchronous gap ===========================
    | dart:async                               _Completer.completeError
    | package:pub/src/entrypoint.dart 199      Entrypoint.acquireDependencies.<async>
    | ===== asynchronous gap ===========================
    | dart:async                               _Future.then
    | package:pub/src/entrypoint.dart 152      Entrypoint.acquireDependencies.<async>
    | ===== asynchronous gap ===========================
    | dart:async                               Future.Future.microtask
    | package:pub/src/entrypoint.dart          Entrypoint.acquireDependencies
    | package:pub/src/command/get.dart 30      GetCommand.run
    | package:args/command_runner.dart 178     CommandRunner.runCommand.<fn>
    | dart:async                               Future.Future.sync
    | package:args/command_runner.dart 131     CommandRunner.runCommand
    | package:pub/src/command_runner.dart 130  PubCommandRunner.runCommand.<async>.<fn>
    | dart:async                               Future.Future.sync
    | package:pub/src/utils.dart 103           captureErrors.<fn>
    | package:stack_trace                      Chain.capture
    | package:pub/src/utils.dart 117           captureErrors
    | package:pub/src/command_runner.dart 130  PubCommandRunner.runCommand.<async>
```

I expanded the version to include anything between 0.0.2 and 0.4.0 and it fails. It is definitely throwing a no version found error even though I can manually download the versions from the web.

Comment: I updated my answer. Just prepending your angular2 dpendency version with `^` should fix your issue, except you have a specific reason to block the `*.45` version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue with `pub`. If it can't resolve a matching set of dependencies it sometimes prints misleading messages.

```
pub upgrade --verbose
```

should reveal more information that allows to investigate what dependencies `pub` is unable to find compatible versions of.

The conflict is the `protobuf` package.
`appengine` `0.3.2` depends on `protobuf` `0.5.0`
`angular2` `2.0.0-alpha.44` depends on `protobuf` `0.4.2`
but `angular2` `2.0.0-alpha.45` also depends on `protobuf` `0.5.0`

If you change your angular dependency to

```
angular2: ^2.0.0-alpha.44
```

or

```
angular2: 2.0.0-alpha.45
```

or

```
angular2: ^2.0.0-alpha
```

pub can resolve all dependencies just fine.